# Email counter - function to return how many emails the user has

Tags: c++, file, counter

I'm making a very basic email server and I need a function to show me how many emails the inbox of a user has. Each email sent has the word "#email" at the top so I'm using it as a keyword do count how many emails, but is not working and I don't know why. Can someone please tell me what is wrong or put me in the right direction??
thanks

```
int GetInboxCount(std::string username)
{
std::ifstream email(username + "-inbox.txt"); //opens the inbox file
std::string item;
int count = 0;
  while(!email.eof()) //read the file until the end
  {
    email >> item;
    if(item == "#email") //search for the word #email that is at the top of every email in the inbox
    {
        ++count;

    }
  }
email.close();
return count; //it should return the numbers of emails
```

Comment: `while(!email.eof())` : [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) Most likely side effect is of-by-one on the count.

Comment: Question cannot be answered in its current state without guesswork. We need a sample of the email text file to make decent parsing suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplice your task you need to use `std::find()` to find the keyword `#email` on the item string. Also use `while(email>>item)` instead of `while(!email.eof())`

Comment: Easily fooled by placing "#email" somewhere inside the email message.

Comment: @user4581301 ok, but thats a design problem not a question problem, maybe the first five characters.

Comment: I agree with you. I don't think the question is currently in a state where it can be answered.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this... I know is easily fooled just by writing #email wherever, but that's the way the problem is. I need a function to count how many "#email" can find in the file I'm opening(username+ "-inbox.txt) and return me a number. @user4581301

Comment: @CristinaChung please explain how your current code fails to work. Put that in your question. Having to guess what is wrong does not make it an answerable question as far as StackOverflow is concerned.

Comment: @Cristina are you sure the file is being opened in the first place? That is currently not being tested.

Comment: Good point. Maybe the file is in a different folder than the current working directory so it is not read at all. Properly using a debugger (single step through this function looking at the variables) should help determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: @drescherjm so this functions returns the count and then I print it, but is not printing...let me check if it is opening the file. Thanks

Comment: A debugger should help with that.